# Валидация XML по схеме XSD - Как определить элемент, в котором находится ошибочный атрибут?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Пишу программу проверки файла XML на соответствие схемы XSD.
Общий код:

```
    private void buttonCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                
                string xmlFileName = tFileXML.Text; // поле ввода файла XML
                string xsdFileName = tFileXSD.Text; // поле ввода файла XSD
                tMessage.Text = ""; // поле сообщения об ошибке
                // пробуем определить целевое пространство имен (targetNameSpace) из файла схемы
                // и проверить, что оно соответствует значению атрибута xmlns элемента <Файл>
                // (для файлов запросов targetNamespace не указан, так что "")
                XmlDocument xsd = new XmlDocument();
                try
                {
                   xsd.Load(xsdFileName);
                } catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    tMessage.Text = "Ошибка в файле схемы " + xsdFileName+"\n"+ex.Message;
                    return;
                }
                string targetNamespace = xsd.DocumentElement.GetAttribute("targetNamespace");
                XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
                settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
                settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
                settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
                settings.Schemas.Add(targetNamespace, xsdFileName);
                settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);
                XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFileName, settings);
                while (reader.Read()) { }
                reader.Close();
                if (tMessage.Text.Length == 0)
                {
                    tMessage.AppendText("Успешно");
                }
            } // buttonCheck_Click
            public void ValidationCallBack(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
            {
                IXmlLineInfo lineInfo = sender as IXmlLineInfo;
                XmlReader r = (XmlReader)sender;
                if (r.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Attribute)
                {
// как здесь получить имя элемента, в котором находится ошибочный атрибут?
                    tMessage.AppendText(String.Format("Line {0} Column {1}: Ошибка: {2}\r\n\r\n", lineInfo.LineNumber, lineInfo.LinePosition,
                       e.Message));
                }
                else
                {
                    tMessage.AppendText(String.Format("Line {0} Column {1}: Элемент <{2}>, Ошибка: {3}\r\n\r\n", lineInfo.LineNumber, lineInfo.LinePosition,
                        r.Name, e.Message));
                }
    }
```

Если есть проблема с *атрибутом* какого-то элемента, то как получить этот самый проблемный элемент, чтобы вывести подробное сообщение? Т.к. одноименные атрибуты могут быть в разных элементах, а бывают файлы XML в одну строку.

В процедуре ValidationCallBack() из XmlREader надо как-то получить элемент, на котором произошла ошибка и выдать его название. Но как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов:

```
if (r.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Attribute)
{
    string attrName = r.Name;
    r.MoveToElement(); // перемещаем читатель к элементу, в котором находится атрибут
    string elemName = r.Name; // получаем имя элемента

    tMessage.AppendText(...);

    r.MoveToAttribute(attrName); // обязательно возвращаем ридер в прежнее состояние
}
```

Таким образом мы получим имя элемента. Но если узлов с таким именем в xml много, то хотелось бы получить полный путь (xpath) к нему.

Сохранять путь будем в стеке. Вводим дополнительное поле:

```
Stack<string> nodes;
```

Код чтения-валидации становится следующим:

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlFileName, settings))
{
    nodes = new Stack<string>();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && !reader.IsEmptyElement)
            nodes.Push(reader.Name);
        else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
            nodes.Pop();
    }
}
```

То есть по мере чтения xml добавляем в стек имена узлов. При выходе из узла удаляем его из стека.

Изменяем обработчик события:

```
string xpath = string.Join("/", nodes.Reverse());

if (r.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Attribute)
{
    string attrName = r.Name;
    r.MoveToElement();
    string elemName = r.Name;

    string fullXpath = xpath + "/" + elemName;

    tMessage.AppendText(...); // тут используем fullXpath

    r.MoveToAttribute(attrName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто сделайте ваш XML всегда отформатированным и с отступом (indented). Таким образом, значения в lineInfo.LineNumber, lineInfo.LinePosition будут очень полезны.

Остальное - зависит от парсера XML.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Что надо!

Comment: @PeterLebedev, Рад слышать, что предложенное решение работает на вас. Пожалуйста, не забудьте пометить ответ как «Ответ».